# Need to invoke 2 or more action using xamarin hybridwebview

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to create 2 or more actions to invoke from my javascript to c# using hybridwebview.

I followed this documentation and everything works so far.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

In my content page I want to achieve this second action.

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => Application.Current.MainPage = new ProfilePage());
```

Is there a possibility for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility for this?

Of course you can ! Check the following code.

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction (data => {

    DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK");
    //...
    Application.Current.MainPage = new ProfilePage();
   //...

   otherMethod();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also able to solve the problem but this also should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just that might help others with the same problem.
I solved the problem by doing below.

I changed the Action to a List in custom control.

```
List<Action<string>> actions;
```

Then I pass to RegisterAction as a List.

```
List<Action<string>> actions = new List<Action<string>>();
actions.Add(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));            
actions.Add(data => Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage());            
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(actions);
```

In custom control, I changed the Invoke method.
From JS, I will pass a formatted string (JSON) then I can manipulate what to do.
For this sample I just used a simple formatted string for testing.

```
var sWhat = data.Split(new[] { ";-;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);                        
actions[int.Parse(sWhat[0].ToString())].Invoke(data);
```